# gwh problem with intellij: The response could not be deserialized

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, gwt

When I build the project and start tomcat from eclipse then everything works fine.

Now when I start tomcat from intellij i get this error message, after logging into the webapplication: 
The response could not be deserialized
I have tried following:

1. invallidate intellij cache and restart
2. rebuild project
3. remove tomcat content under C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\dev
4. reload maven projects

No success. I am using tomcat 9 from intellij idea 2018.2.1. What else could I try/check?

[image]

Comment: How does your runConfig for the tomcat look like?

Comment: Did it work before? F.e.: if you try it with Eclipse?

Comment: for eclipse it works, when open it with intellij it doesnt work any more. When I reopen with eclipse it doesnt work any more as well. after rebuild from eclipse again it works.

Comment: I have updted the description with tomcat configuration

Comment: Are you trying to use a external server for GWT development or do you want to run a compiled GTW application?

Comment: I want to run a compiled GWT and don't develop any GWT stuf but need it for backend development

Comment: I'll do this all the time and it works. First, I would check, if the GWT content is included in the deployed artifact.

Comment: @ElHoss where and what exactly to check? I hate Intellij, many poblems than eclipse